# Serial data filtering

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, type-conversion, temperature

I'm using an LM-35 temperature sensor on an Arduino Leonardo.
Then I use Python to connect with this Arduino and download the temperature value through serial port.

The code is working, and Arduino is sending data but what I need to do is to separate the numeric value from the other characters that are coming together.
When I run the code, I obtain results like that on my monitor:

```
b'26.88\r\n'
<class 'bytes'>
```

What I need to do is to separate the value 26.88 (Celsius temperature) as a float, but I don't know how can I do that?

Here is my code below:

```
import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)

while 1:
    str1 = ser.readline()
    print (str1)
    print (type(str1))
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to do just 'float(str1)'? There's no problem for me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip out the \r and \n characters. Try this:

```
import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)

while 1:
    str1 = ser.readline()

    finalValue = str1.decode('utf-8').replace('\r','').replace('\n','')
    print (float(finalValue))
```

Comment: Instead of using two calls to replace, a more generic solution is one call to strip(), which removes all white space from the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: True but strip() won't remove such characters in the middle.

Comment: @hikerjobs If you ever get such a string from the Arduino temperature sensor it indicates some kind of hardware problem.  You would be better off getting an error message than pretending that you can actually parse it.

Comment: Granted readline() will read till a \n character and stop, but what about a \r character? I wasn't able to find anything in the official Pyserial documentation about \r. As to the hardware problem, I agree. Sometimes also the connection itself. Also, building upon your line of thought, ideally, he should be a using a timeout when using readline(). Otherwise, it could get stuck forever waiting for the newline.

Comment: I tried  to do as suggested, but the result is the same and now the values are repeated. There is no problem with the temperature sensor on arduino since it returns the correct value when i use any serial monitor program. The problem is to parse the data since it´s a byte class and filter the correct value.

Comment: The repetitions were due to the multiple print statements. I've removed them in the answer above. Also, changed it a bit to decode the byte string to a string which might fix your problem. Can you try again and show the output?

Comment: I´m using pyhton version 3.6.4, it´s giving a syntax error in print float last line. :-/

Comment: Need the (...) for Python 3. Fixed. Try now.